# Twitter Callback URL opens up after posting text on twitter in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, twitter

I am providing `google url` as *call back url* in my application. But after posting the text to my page my application opens that Google page in foreground which is of-course its a bug in application.

I just need that after posting the text control returns to my application.
I am using the code from this link :
[Twitter-is-Integrated-in-BlackBerry](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Twitter-is-Integrated-in-BlackBerry/m-p/1698157)

If I don't provide the Call back URL, twitter demands for PIN NUMBER before **login**.
please suggest me for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [TwitterAPIMe](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/pages/Home#Functionalities) as it is.It is Simple to Use No need for PIN based Authentication and Library will Automatically Redirect you after login from Twitter to your application. You have to change in some native code of API that...

- Go To: com.twitterapime.xauth.ui.**OAuthDialogWrapper Class**
- Go to method called **trackUrl(String url)**
- Now Replace the Code:

> if (url.startsWith(callbackUrl)&& oauthListener != null) { .... ... ..
>   }

With:

> if (url.indexOf(callbackUrl)!=-1 && oauthListener != null) { .... ...
>   .. }

That's it. Simply get AccessToken inside **onAurthorize** method and access Twitter API. Most of the functionalities and methods are covered inside this api.